# Please how can i enable heroku to automatically perform collectstatic after disabling it?

Tags: heroku

i disabled it at first using

`heroku config set:DISABLE COLLECTSTATIC=1`

Now i want to enable it

I have tried
`heroku config set:DISABLE COLLECTSTATIC=0`

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please add what errors you are getting after you tried disabling it. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: it disabled successfully and i was able to deploy without any staticfiles error. I want to enable it now because the site doesn't have any styles to it, the code i tried to enable it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: i am not getting errors

Comment: Did you redeploy after doing this? (Side note: personally, I'd use [`heroku config:unset COLLECTSTATIC`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#remove-a-config-var) to avoid a useless environment variable, but what you did should work.)